# DateAdd -1 day in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone please help me here. I am trying to print the date as -1 day in case the time falls between 12:00 Am to 04:00 AM. If it is from 04:00 Am to 11:59:59 Pm should show current date.

I am struggling a lot but no desired result.

```
If cTime < "04:00:00 AM" Or cTime >= "12:00:00 AM" Then    
    Workbooks("Check").Sheets(1).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)    
Else    
    Workbooks("Check").Sheets(1).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = Date
End If
```

Comment: Date literals should use `#` not `"` E.g.  `#04:00:00 AM#`

Comment: @AlexK. you should post as answer, so future users will be able to find the solution easily

Comment: I have tried this before and now as well, but still it shows as 02-Jul-17.

Comment: Well `DateAdd("d", -1, Date)` returns `02-Jul-17` for me because that is yesterdays date (in my timezone) - What is your issue with that value?

Comment: The local time here is 07:57 PM which means it should show as 03-Jul-17 not the 02-Jul-17.

Comment: What does `msgbox Date` show you?

Comment: It shows as 7/3/2017.

Comment: so -1 from that is 7/2/2017 which is correct

Comment: But this should execute `Workbooks("Check").Sheets(1).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = Date` since the local time is 08:13 Pm here.

Comment: Since you are using `...Or cTime >= "12:00:00 AM"...` you are validating all times after 12:00 am.  This is because you are using the `OR` statement.  Every time after 12am is therefore "true".  If you use an `AND` statement, then you'll find times only in the range.

Comment: You could also just drop off the `Or cTime >= "12:00:00 AM"` from your code since there is nothing less than 12am.  There is no reason to check for that unless someone is going to go into your code and change the hard coded `"12:00:00 AM"` to something different.

Comment: You get that CTime is a built-in conversion function and that you should **never** repurpose the names of built in functions, properties or methods as the name(s) of your dimmed vars?

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of what cTime is, but in the past when I have worked with time operations like this [since they are simple times], why not try the Hour function?

```
If Hour(Now) >= 0 And Hour(Now) <= 4 Then
    Workbooks("Check").Sheets(1).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
Else    
    Workbooks("Check").Sheets(1).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = Date
End If
```

For your original code, you also should make sure you are using AND, and not OR.   If the current time is 11:00AM (which it is roughly for me), then that meets the criteria `Hour(Now) > 0 (12AM)`. But it doesn't meet the criteria `Hour(Now) < 4 (4AM)`. Since it's an OR, it only needs to meet `A`, not `A and B`.